# Configurable Datasource Object Using Encryptionutils

Tags: java, oracle, spring-data

I am creating a datasource object in the following way in a microservice:

```
@Autowired
private EncryptionUtil encryptionutils;

public ComboPooledDataSource appDataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        DatasourceDto datasourceDto = null;
        try {
            datasourceDto = encryptionutils.getDbCredentials("servicename", "oracle", env.getProperty("env"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            log.info().logException("Exception",e);
        }
        if (datasourceDto == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(datasourceDto.getPassword()) || StringUtils
                .isEmpty(datasourceDto.getHost()) || StringUtils.isEmpty(datasourceDto.getUsername())) {
            throw new DBDetailsNotFoundException("Failed to get db credentials");
        }
        dataSource.setDriverClass(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName());
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(datasourceDto.getHost());
        dataSource.setUser(datasourceDto.getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(datasourceDto.getPassword());
        configureConnectionPool(dataSource);
        return dataSource;
}
```

This code is part of the microservice and it works fine.
Now, I need to separate out all database configurations from this microservice and create a standalone database service, which will be later used as a jar by the microservice and other microservices.

This actually reads database information from a secrets yml file which has the oracle related information based on a hierarchy like this:

```
servicename:
  oracle:
  username:
  host:
  password: 
servicename2:
  oracle:
  username:
  host:
  password:
```

where "servicename", "servicename2" are the microservice names.

Now, the issue I am facing is in this line:

```
datasourceDto = encryptionutils.getDbCredentials("servicename", "oracle", env.getProperty("env"));
```

The problem is that earlier the database related code was part of every microservice which needs database connection and the name of the particular microservice was hard-coded in this line as "servicename" or "servicename2" respectively to access the corresponding database information. So, when I was connecting to the database for a particular microservice, this was working fine.

Now since I am moving this code to a common Database service module, the "servicename" can no longer be hardcoded because this database service will be used by every other microservice as well.

If I hardcode it to one servicename, other services also will end up connecting that service's database, which is not desired here. So, my question is how can I make this "servicename" configurable in that line so that when microservice "servicename" tries to access the database, then the corresponding database info is fetched for "servicename" from the db secrets yml and when "servicename2" microservice wants to connect to the database it fetches db information for "servicename2".